# How to defocus a program without letting it know it is out of WinAPI focus

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, gaming, multiple-users, hook

There is a need for two of us with my friend to use one PC at the same time.  I have a gaming PC, 2 screens, a gamepad — sounds like a great multi-user environment, eh?  Not so fast.
The problem is: most of the games, even if windowed, require to be focused in order to keep running. Few games have a switchable option for that.
Is there a way to hook WinAPI focus/defocus events so that the process will never receive "defocused" event?  Or is there a fixed pattern by which I can find such a WinAPI check in program's executable and disassemble it?

Comment: I think you're going to run into a bigger problem in figuring out how to route input to the proper window.

Comment: I don't think so considering I am only using XInput library for the games I want to fool.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Multipoint Server think you have everything listed.

Old software hardware implementation:[Jetway's 915P-TWIN Mobo: One PC, Two Users](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/jetway,924.html)

Software - [BeTwin](http://www.thincomputinginc.com/product_pc_sharing_betwin.aspx).

Virtual box, as variant.

WinAPI:

[Should I use DirectInput or Windows message loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165230/should-i-use-directinput-or-windows-message-loop/)

[Multiple keyboards and low-level hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91234/multiple-keyboards-and-low-level-hooks)

[Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard)

Comment: Hardware isn't an option. BeTween seems to only work for 2000/XP. Mouse and keyboard controls doesn't have to be shared as I only need a gamepad for games.